# SocketIO: Is there a way to send a token, with every message?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, authorization

I know that SocketIO supports query parameters for the initial connection, like:

```
const socket = io({
  query: {
    token: 'cde'
  }
});
```

This is all good and nice, but i'm wondering whether there is a way to "append" some data to every message sent from the client, to be validated on the server.

From the client api docs, it seems the "emit" method doesn't support any options object, but maybe i'm missing something elsewhere.

How can it be done? Of course i could just send some additional data as a **last argument** for the the emit function, and then use the arguments object to extract it, but that doesn't seem as a very clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.emit is similar to node.js's ws send, i.e. it sends **raw data** frames to the server, so the option to attach the token as last argument seems to fit.

What you can do to get a cleaner solution is to abstract emit in another method that accept a message obj as argument, then it will add your token to each request and finally emit it.